# Java Unchecked Assignement

Tags: java, list, generics, collections

I have a function defined which returns a generic list of whatever objects which are implementing **PaginationData** interface

```
private <T> List<T> paginate(int pageNumber, int pageSize, int totalAvailable, PaginatedResponse paginatedResponse, String url) {
   List<T> listOfObjects = new ArrayList();
        while (pageNumber * pageSize <= totalAvailable) {
           paginatedResponse = sendRequest(url + "?pageNumber=" + pageNumber, paginatedResponse.getClass());

           listOfObjects.addAll(paginatedResponse
           .getPaginationData()
           .getPaginatedObjectsList());
 
           pageNumber++;
   }
  return listOfObjects;
}
```

and PaginatedResponse defined like this

```
public interface PaginatedResponse {

    Pagination getPagination();

    PaginationData getPaginationData();
}
```

Where PaginationData is an interface defined

```
public interface PaginationData<T> {

    List<T> getPaginatedObjectsList();
}
```

sendRequest method looks like this

```
private <T> T sendRequest(String url, Class<T> clazz) {
   HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.send(url);
   
   //Jackson's object mapper to transform the result
   // but this result can be also other type than the PaginatedResponse
   
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(httpResponse.getEntity(), clazz);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ParsingException(e);
        }
   
}
```

Everything works fine I'm just getting a warning when invoking .addAll() method on the **listOfObjects** variable.
This warning states : **Unchecked assignment, java.util.List to java.util.Collection<? extends T> Reason, paginatedResponse.getPaginationData() has raw type so the result of getPaginatedObjectList() is erased.**

So the question is how to get rid of the warning when I'm just returning generic objects wrapped in the list and I'm getting them from the generic paginated response which can be of whatever type which implements PaginatedResponse.

Comment: You're using [raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) in a few places. Start by avoiding that.

Answer (score 0):

In your `interface PaginatedResponse`, `PaginationData` is of raw type. You should correct it as:

```java
public interface PaginatedResponse<T> { // type parameter is required here or at the least at method level getPaginationData()
    Pagination getPagination();
    PaginationData<T> getPaginationData(); // this will remove raw type usage
}
```

Then, update `paginate(...)` method as below (argument `PaginatedResponse paginatedResponse` to `PaginatedResponse<T> paginatedResponse` to remove raw type usage):

```java
private <T> List<T> paginate(int pageNumber, int pageSize, int totalAvailable, PaginatedResponse<T> paginatedResponse, String url) {
  // ...
}
```

Additionally, initialise the list as `List<T> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<>();` instead of `List<T> listOfObjects = new ArrayList();` to remove raw type usage.

---

**Edit for follow up question about `sendRequest()` method:**

Please use [`TypeReference`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html) from jackson instead of `Class` for `sendRequest()` method. Please check topic "Type erasure" for more details.

Define the method like this:

```java
private <T> T sendRequest(String url, TypeReference<T> typeReference) {
    // ... your original code ...
    return objectMapper.readValue(httpResponse.getEntity(), typeReference);
    // ... your original code ...
}
```

Call it like this:

```java
    paginatedResponse = sendRequest(url + "?pageNumber=" + pageNumber, new TypeReference<PaginatedResponse<T>>() {});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Viral.. unfortunately it only moved warning to the             paginatedResponse = sendRequest(url + "?pageNumber=" + pageNumber); method which is returning private<T> T sendRequest(url)

Comment: @MarkyMark, there is no reference/detail regarding `sendRequest()` method in your question. Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: I've updated the question to show the sendRequest method. Please check

Comment: @MarkyMark, please check topic "Type erasure" for more details. In your case, you should use `TypeReference` from jackson instead of class for `sendRequest()` method. Define like this: `private <T> T sendRequest(String url, TypeReference<T> typeReference)`, use it like this: `objectMapper.readValue(httpResponse.getEntity(), typeReference);` and pass it like this: `paginatedResponse = sendRequest(url + "?pageNumber=" + pageNumber, new TypeReference<PaginatedResponse<T>>() {});`

Comment: I have updated this answer with details for better understanding.

Comment: ok, that makes sense but.. on the other hand how can I build new TypeReference for a class which implements the PaginatedResponse.. For example when I call ```paginate(1, 100, 300, Account accountsPaginatedResponse, url)``` or ```paginate(1, 100, 300, User usersPaginatedResponse, url)```

Comment: Well, that is beyond the scope of original question about warnings about generics. But let me add a possible solution in that case. 1. Update paginate method to: `private <T, U extends PaginatedResponse<T>> List<T> paginate(int pageNumber, int pageSize, int totalAvailable, TypeReference<U> typeReference, String url)`. Here U must be PaginatedResponse or implementer of it. 2. Call sendRequest like this: `PaginatedResponse<T> paginatedResponse = sendRequest("", typeReference);` 3. Call paginate like this: `paginate(1,100,300, new TypeReference<AccountsPaginatedResponse<Integer>>() {}, url)`.